# Signed Applets don't work in IE8/Window 7

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, applet

I have created signed applet for reading file on client side and it is being embedded into HTML page.

I have 2 testing machines having below environment,

**First machine**


Operating System: Window xp
installed JRE: 1.6.0_20
Browser: IE8

**2nd machine**
 
Operating System: Window 7
instaleld JRE: 1.6.0_18
Browser:IE8

When i ran the html page from first machine it is downloading applet successfully however when i ran the same applet from 2nd machine it not downloading applet.

Is it really the problem operating system or JRE build version?

If it not the problem of OS or JRE then what is exactly the problem?

Please help me.

Comment: (Note that 6u24 (1.6.0_24) is the current "secure" version of the JRE.)

Answer (score 1):

enable error log in the browser plugin and see what it says. Without that information there's nothing anyone can tell you (unless maybe there's a very specific bug in the combination of components that fails that someone happens to have encountered before).